# R predicting from multivariate polynomial models

Tags: r, linear-regression

I have 3 columns of data in a dataframe (data) with no headers.

The 1st and 2nd column are the independent variables and the 3rd column is the dependent variable.

I have to fit a polynomial of order 3 in the independent variables.

I did:

```
dm <- data.matrix(data[,1:2])
pmodel <- lm(data.matrix(data[,3])~poly(dm,degree = 3,raw=TRUE))
```

Now how can i predict the answer for a given pair of the independent variables say (0.77,0.36) ?

I tried:

```
predict.lm(pmodel,data.frame(0.77,0.36))
```

But this gives some error saying:

'newdata' had 1 row but variables found have 100 rows

Comment: Is there some special reason for all the calls to data.matrix? Why can't you use names of the columns of data in your lm() call? EDIT: oh, because they're aren't any. Add them.

Comment: @atiretoo how do i add column names? and what difference does it make?

Comment: Well, lots of ways, and I thought that was the answer to your problem, because when you use predict() with lm objects it is much easier if the covariates in the formula are named. But it isn't the answer (or not the whole answer) ... turns out making predictions from multivariate poly() is complicated, for instance see http://r.789695.n4.nabble.com/predict-poly-for-multivariate-data-td4709718.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, there are several problems to deal with. I start by trying to mimic the situation you describe, a data set without names. In fact, if it is a data.frame object (that is, `class(data)` returns data.frame), it has names almost certainly. You can see this if you just run the bit that creates your newdata data.frame:

```
data.frame(0.77,0.36)
```

The automatic names are ugly, but they're there: X0.77 X0.36

But let's get data without names and see what happens.

```
 ## make a matrix without names from iris data
 data <- matrix(unlist(iris[,1:3]),nrow=nrow(iris))

 pmodel <- lm(data[,3]~poly(data[,1:2],degree = 3,raw=TRUE))
 # variable names are ugly
 summary(pmodel)
```

The difficulty without using names is that predict() can't figure out how to map the new values onto the columns in the data unless the labels in the data.frame you pass to the newdata argument match something in the model frame. So in the following code you get a warning because the newdata doesn't have the right names, and doesn't have the right length.

```
 test <- predict.lm(pmodel,data.frame(0.77,0.36))
```

But test has something in it?

```
 all.equal(test,fitted(pmodel)) # TRUE
```

What's happened is that predict() ignored the new data and just returned the fitted values of the model. So, what about using a data.frame with names?

```
 df = as.data.frame(data) 
 names(df) #  automatically creates variable names
 names(df) <- c("X","Y","Z") # change 'em if you want

 pmodel2 <- lm(Z~poly(X,Y,degree=3, raw=TRUE),data=df)
```

We can check that this is the same object as before:

```
 all.equal(coef(pmodel),coef(pmodel2)) # matches except for names
```

But, if we try predict again, we get a different error!

```
 nd <- data.frame(X=0.77,Y=0.36)
 predict(pmodel2,newdata=nd)
```

> Error in `colnames<-`(`*tmp*`, value = apply(z, 1L, function(x)
>   paste(x,  :    attempt to set 'colnames' on an object with less than
>   two dimensions

For reasons that are beyond me but relate to how the polynomial is calculated, you need at least 2 rows of newdata.

```
 nd <- data.frame(X=c(0.77,0.89),Y=c(0.36,0.4))
 predict(pmodel2,newdata=nd)

 # check against fitted values
 predict(pmodel2,newdata=df[1:2,])
 fitted(pmodel2)[1:2]
```

If you really need just one prediction, you can replicate it and throw away one row of the result.

```
nd <- data.frame(X=rep(0.77,times=2),Y=rep(0.36,times=2))
predict(pmodel2,newdata=nd)[1]
```

EDIT: The problem is that the number of columns is unknown, so using the names of the columns in poly() is difficult to do automatically. But! We can do computations with the names. Create the formula like this

```
 ff <- as.formula(paste("Z~poly(",
                  paste0(names(df)[1:2],collapse=", "),
                  ", degree=3,raw=TRUE)"))
```

and then

```
  pmodel <- lm(ff, data=df)
```

There could be a better way to do this, but this works.

Comment: cool! what do i do if the number of variables is not fixed at 2? i certainly can't name them as X,Y .

Comment: check the names that are created automatically and use those -- they are usually V1, V2 etc.

Comment: I meant if the number of variables isn't fixed how do i use them in poly? poly(..., degree = 3, raw = TRUE) ?

Comment: So data is of variable number of columns, and that's why you want to use the matrix version of poly()? Are you sure you want a multivariate polynomial of degree 3? Or are you after all main effects, 2 and 3 way interactions of a set of variables?

Comment: Yeah i am sure it's degree 3 that's what my professor asked me to try, but the number of columns is unknown not variable (i.e is fixed).